# The Client And Service Bindings May Be Mismatched When Changing Endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have a WCF service which works fine, If I do not try and configure the endpoint address. As Soon as I try to edit the endpoint, like so:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://corne-pc:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Magenta/Service1/"));
MaciService.I_MaciWcfServiceClient maci = new MaciService.I_MaciWcfServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
MessageBox.Show(maci.GetUserCount_Single("192.168.1.212", "11010").ToString());
```

I get the following error message when calling to the service:

```
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
http://corne-pc:8733/Design_Time-Addresses/Magenta/Service1. The client and
service bindings may be mismatched.
```

I have found some similar posts, that could not solve my problem. For example, I don't think it could be a soap mismatch, as it works when not altering the endpoint.

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_I_MaciWcfService" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://corne-pc:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Magenta/Service1/"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_I_MaciWcfService"
            contract="MaciService.I_MaciWcfService" name="BasicHttpBinding_I_MaciWcfService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure your client and server config use the same binding. I beleive one is using WSHttp and one BasicHttp. This aligns with the error which means client is sending SOAP12 but server expects SOAP11.